# Find the location and determine the corresponding value of another array having the same location of one array

Tags: matlab, search, matrix, find

If

```
a=[5 8 1 2 6 7 1 4 2 3 7 8];
b=[7 6 3 1 5 4 2 0 1 8 9 4];
```

then

```
a1=[1 7 3]
```

corresponds to a matrix and d should be `[3 4 8]`

`d` is the exact location of the corresponding `a` value. How do I find this value?

Comment: Please clarify the relationship between the matrices... it isn't clear what you're trying for.

Comment: a1 is the value that contains in the array a, first:find the location where the elements a1 occurs in a;secondly, find the corresponding location of the value that is found in b.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, i have posted an answer, i have tested it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
arrayfun(@(x) b(find(a == x, 1, 'first')), a1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
c = []
for i = 1:length(a1)
    index = find(a == a1(i));
    c = [c, index(1)]
end

d = []
for i = 1:length(c)
    d = [d, b(c(i))]
end
```

output is [3 4 8]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to do without `for` loop?

Comment: Rather than `find`ing all occurrences and taking the first value (in the first loop) you can use `find(a==a1(i),1,'first')`

Comment: +1 for figuring out the question. Seeing your answer, I finally get it!

Comment: @chaohuang i cant think of a way.