# Find indices of elements in an array based on a search from another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, matrix, find

Imagine that i have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0];

b = [5, 9, 6];
```

I want to find the indices of the values of b in a (only the first hit) ie:

```
c = [3, 6, 5];
```

Is there an easy Matlab native way to do this without looping and searching.

I have tried to use find() with:

```
find(a == b)
```

and it would work if you did this:

```
for i = 1:length(b)
    index = find(a == b(i));
    c = [c, index(1)]
end
```

But it would be ideal for it to be easier then this.

Comment: MATLAB uses 1-based indexing, so it should read `index(1)` in your loop solution

Comment: Similar to: [Find the location and determine the corresponding value of another array having the same location of one array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11571676/97160)

Comment: @Amro, lol nearly 2 years later and I only just saw your comment. Fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually built into [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). You just need to set the right flag, then it's a one liner and you don't need arrayfun. Versions newer than R2012b use this behavior by default.

Originally, [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) would return the last occurence if there are several, the R2012a flag makes it return the first one.

Here's my testing results:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6];
b = [5, 9, 6];

[~,c] = ismember(b,a,'R2012a');
>> c
c =
     3     6     5
```

Answer (score 20):

You can compact your for loop easily with arrayfun into a simple one-liner:

```
arrayfun(@(x) find(a == x,1,'first'), b )
```

also see [Scenia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336707/1162609) for newer matlab versions (>R2012b).

Comment: arrayfun is no faster than for-loops

Comment: @niceman I never said it was... And I believe in some situations it wíll be just as fast or faster when the JIT kicks in (especially on multicore setups). On the other side, some people just like the oneliner-capability of `arrayfun`. For this question it actually doesn't even matter, as you're better of using [Scenia's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21336707/1162609)

Answer (score 5):

This is a fix to the `ismember` approach that [@Pursuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572526/97160) suggested. This way it handles multiple occurrences of one of the numbers, and returns the result in the correct order:

```
[tf,loc] = ismember(a,b);
tf = find(tf);
[~,idx] = unique(loc(tf), 'first');
c = tf(idx);
```

The result:

```
>> c
c =
     3     6     5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6];
b = [5, 9, 6];
[r c]=find(bsxfun(@eq,a,b')');
[~,ia,~]=unique(c,'first');
>> r(ia)

ans =

     3
     6
     5
```

Note: I added an extra `6` at the end of `a` to demonstrate finding only the first occurrence of each value.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
[c,ind_a] = intersect(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ismember`?

```
c_logical_mask = ismember(a, b);
```

or

```
c_indexes = find(ismember(a, b));
```

Comment: A couple of things: This doesn't find only the first occurrence of each value of `b` in `a`, and it doesn't leave the indices in the right order either.

Comment: @tmpearce: I posted a fix of this

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0];
b = [5, 9, 6];
c = dsearchn(a',b');
```

Matlab requires a and b need to be column vectors, hence the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [@tmpearce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572328/2586922), but possibly faster:

```
[valid, result] = max(bsxfun(@eq, a(:), b(:).')); %'// max finds first occurrence
result = result(valid); %// this is necessary in case some value of b is not in a
```